# Bash function to get and decode kubernetes secrets

Tags: bash, shell, kubernetes

I'm trying to code a bash function to get and decode a kubernetes secret's data in just one short command. My idea is to have something like `kgsecd -n <namespace> <secret-name> <secret-data>` that is just mapped to `kubectl get secret -n <namespace> <secret-name> -o "jsonpath={.data.<secret-data>}" | base64 -d`. I have already coded it as follows:

```sh
  kgsecd() {
    secretData="${@: -1}"
    kubectlParams=(${@:1:-1})
    echo "kubectl get secret ${kubectlParams} -o \"jsonpath={.data.$secretData}\" | base64 -d"
    kubectl get secret "${kubectlParams}" -o "jsonpath={.data.$secretData}" | base64 -d;
  }
```

However, I'm struggling to make it work as when I call it, it doesn't show any output in the terminal (apart from that from the `echo` sentence), but if I copy&paste and executed the output of the echo sentence, it works as expected. Let me show you what I mean with an example:

```sh
$> kgsecd -n my-ns my-secret secret-data
kubectl get secret -n my-ns my-secret -o "jsonpath={.data.secret-data}" | base64 -d
$>
```

But when I execute `kubectl get secret -n my-ns my-secret -o "jsonpath={.data.secret-data}" | base64 -d`, I get the expected result.

Comment: Kubernetes Secrets are not "encrypted" when returned from `kubectl get secret` - but **base64 encoded**.

Comment: Mmmmm....`echo $(kubectl get secret "${kubectlParams}" -o "jsonpath={.data.$secretData}" | base64 -d)`?

Comment: Yeah, you're right @Jonas. I wanted to say decode instead of decrypt. I'm sorry, I'm not a native English speaker and made a mistake :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `bash` try the following, only change is the way `kubectlParams` is assigned. Here, `kubectlParams` is assigned with 1st arg to penultimate(`$#-1`) arguments.

Also, `"${kubectlParams}"` if quoted, then will be considered as a command. Eg: `-n my-ns my-secret` would be consider as as a single string. and  it would be considered as a single string , and that string is argument to `kubectl`. kubectl understand `-n` , `my-ns`, `my-secret` , but not `-n my-ns mysecret`.

```
kgsecd() {
 secretData="${@: -1}"
 kubectlParams=${@:1:$#-1}

 echo "kubectl get secret ${kubectlParams} -o \"jsonpath={.data.$secretData}\" | base64 -d"
 kubectl get secret ${kubectlParams} -o "jsonpath={.data.$secretData}" | base64 -d
}
```

Execution output:

```
#test secret created:
kubectl create secret  generic my-secret -n my-ns --from-literal=secret-data=helloooooo


#function output
kgsecd -n my-ns my-secret secret-data
kubectl get secret -n my-ns my-secret -o "jsonpath={.data.secret-data}" | base64 -d
helloooooo
```

#manual command execution output:

```
kubectl get secret -n my-ns my-secret -o "jsonpath={.data.secret-data}" | base64 -d
helloooooo
```

`zsh` solution(see comments by OP):

```
kgsecd() { kubectl get secret ${@:1:-1} -o "jsonpath={.data.${@: -1}}" | base64 -d }
```

Comment: I am using bash.  I will delete the answer as it did not helped in your environment.

Comment: Thank you so much! I finally managed to make it work. However, the problem is not only in the `kubectlParams` assignation as you pointed out, but also in the way it's used in the call to `kubectl` command. In my version, I had it surrounded by double quotes `"${kubectlParams}"`, which prevented it from working well. It would be nice if you could edit your answer and add this detail also.

Comment: yes, in my answer it is not quoted. else it would be considered as a single string , and that string is argument to `kubectl`. kubectl understand `-n` , `my-ns`, `my-secret` , but not `-n my-ns mysecret`.

Comment: Thanks so much for your detailed explanation. Unfortunately, it seems it still doesn't work in zsh but it actually works in bash (I tried it out), so maybe you could also add a note about this. Anyway, I'm going to accept your answer as correct.

Comment: I finally managed to craft a version that works in ZSH: `kgsecd() { kubectl get secret ${@:1:-1} -o "jsonpath={.data.${@: -1}}" | base64 -d }`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the previous answer, which is actually correct, here it is the zsh-compliant "long version" of the function:

```
kgsecd() {
 secretData=${@: -1}
 kubectlParams=${@:1:-1}
 kubectl get secret ${=kubectlParams} -o "jsonpath={.data.$secretData}" | base64 -d
}
```

The main differences to make it zsh-compliant are:

- `kubectlParams=${@:1:-1}` use `:-1}` instead of `:$#-1}` to get items until the penultimate element of the params array.
- `kubectl get secret ${=kubectlParams} ...` be aware of the equal sign in `${=kubectlParams}`. This is because zsh unlike bash, doesn't split array items on variable substitution, so you have to add the equal sign in case you want this behaviour.